# Normalizing, returns divide by zero error

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, normalization

I have a sensor reading in data, that I wish to normalize.

```
f1020=[]
While True:
    cmnd = getMsrMnt(filter.1020) #command to get a sensor value
    f1020.append(cmnd.measurement) #write the sensor value to the above array
    norm_f1020 = [(float(i)-min(f1020))/(max(f1020)-min(f1020)) for i in f1020] #normalize the data
```

However, at this point, I get the following error

> ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

This will always happen at index zero because there is only one value in the array at the moment! How can I get around this error with the present `norm_f1020` technique, if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by 2 ways:

1. add to the division really small value
2. because it should be something that divided by 0, you can do try except and add float('inf') instead of the result of the division

but I would go with the first way:

```py
f1020=[]
While True:
    cmnd = getMsrMnt(filter.1020) #command to get a sensor value
    f1020.append(cmnd.measurement) #write the sensor value to the above array
    norm_f1020 = [(float(i)-min(f1020))/((max(f1020)-min(f1020) + 10**-100)) for i in f1020] #normalize the data
```

Just make sure that the value that you have selected isn't too small (for example at `1/(0 + 10**-500)` I got `ZeroDivisionError`.